# Types of property 'X' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Here is what I am trying to do. I wanted to write a `addIdToAnimal` function that takes any Animal, and adds id to it.

Each animal has `animalType` attribute which is a an `enum`.

My questions are:

1. Having `animalType` is to help identify which `AnimalType` an object is in the later process (eg. interate over `Animal[]` and run different logic depending on `AnimalType`). But I am not sure if it is the best practice to define a type with a fixed value. Other suggestions are very welcome.
2. Currently `addIdToAnimal` throws typescript error: `Types of property 'animalType' are incompatible.` How can I fix this?

```js
enum AnimalType {
  Mammal,
  Fish,
}

type Animal =  Lion | Salmon;

type Lion = {
  id: number;
  animalType: AnimalType.Mammal;
  detail: LionDetail;
};

type Salmon = {
  id: number;
  animalType: AnimalType.Fish;
  detail: SalmonDetail;
};

interface LionDetail {
  roar: () => void
}

interface SalmonDetail {
  swim: () => void
}

const addIdToAnimal = (animal: Omit<Animal, 'id'>): Animal => {
  return {
    id: 1,
    ...animal,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Lion = {
  id: number;
  animalType: AnimalType;
  detail: LionDetail;
};

type Salmon = {
  id: number;
  animalType: AnimalType;
  detail: SalmonDetail;
};
```

Putting `AnimalType.Mammal` or `AnimalType.Fish` are values not types.

Object Oriented approach of what you want to achieve

```
interface ILion {
    id: number;
    readonly animalType: AnimalType;
    detail: LionDetail;
}

class Lion implements ILion { 
    constructor(id: number) { 
        this.animalType = AnimalType.Mammal;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

let newLion = new Lion(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. What you said is absolutely correct. Is there any way to ensure `Lion` always has `animalType: AnimalType.Mammal`?

Comment: the best object oriented approach of doing this is you can create a Lion class and in the constructor you can set `animalType` as `AnimalType.Mammal`

whenever you want to create a new lion instance you will get the animalType property preset.

Comment: An example of OO approach is updated in the answer.

Comment: I came across this situation somewhat frequently. I will see if it makes sense in our context. Thanks a lot!